# Should I say “no food In this event” or “no food at this event”?

Tags: grammar

Is this with correct grammar: no food served in this event? Should it be “at this event”?

Comment: What are you trying to say?  That no free food will be available, no vendors will be supplying food in exchange for money, or attendees are not permitted to bring in their own food?  And what is the nature of the "event" -- a "fair" where people stroll around, a concert/lecture, or something else?

Comment: A performance was the event and no free food was what I was trying to say. I used: no food will be provided at the event. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It should be "served at the event."  An event is in a place, but it's not the place, it's what's occurring there.  To say food is "served in" something usually means that thing is a dish or building.

Comment: Thanks! No food will be provided at the event was what I used.